# scrape a web page with scrapy dosen't return page content

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a web page with [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) I noticed it won't work when I parsed web page throw my ipython shell it returned this:

```
'دانلود کتاب و کتاب صوتی با طاقچه\n        // more info: http://angulartics.github.io/\n        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {\n            i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {\n                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)\n            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),\n                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)\n        })(window, document, \'script\', \'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\', \'ga\');\n        ga(\'create\', \'UA-57199074-1\', { \'cookieDomain\': location.hostname == \'localhost\' ? \'none\' : \'auto\' });\n        ga(\'require\', \'ec\');\n    Taaghche works best with JavaScript enabled{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "https://taaghche.ir/", "name": "طاقچه", "alternateName": "نزدیکترین کتاب فروشی شهر", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "https://taaghche.ir/search?term={search_term_string}", "query-input": "required name=search_term_string" } }{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "Organization", "url": "https://taaghche.ir", "logo": "https://taaghche.ir/assets/images/taaghchebrand.png", "contactPoint": [{ "@type": "ContactPoint", "telephone": "+۹۸-۲۱-۸۸۱۴۹۸۱۶", "contacttype": "customer support", "areaServed": "IR" }] }'
```

more like a json response. how can I scrape throw it? by the way my **scraper** looks like this:

```
class Taaghche(scrapy.Spider):
name='taaghche'
def start_requests(self):
    urls = []

    link = 'https://taaghche.ir/search?term='

    data = pd.read_csv('books.csv')
    titles = data.title
    for title in titles:
        key = title.replace(" ", "%20")
        urls.append(link+key)

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_front)


def parse_front(self,response):
    booklinks = response.xpath('//a[@class="book-link"][1]/@href').extract_first()
    #print(booklinks)
    #for booklink in booklinks:
    yield response.follow(url =booklinks, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self,response):
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Website content is not render by server side.The Content of the website is  rendered by JavaScript:

In this case you need use either.

- Selenium (Integrate [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) with scrapy )
- Check request url in network tab. There might be API url and you can get data from url.

There might be other possible Solutions.

Comment: turned out it uses a simple api

Comment: Easier than Parsing via API :D